# $p$-adic Hodge theoretic properties of global Galois representations via $\ell$-Frobenii

Tags: galois-theory, galois-representations, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $G_{\mathbb{Q},S} = \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb Q)$ where $\mathbb Q_S$ is the largest algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$ unramified outside a finite set of places $S$. Then the union over $\ell$ of the conjugacy classes of a Frobenius element $\mathrm{Frob}_\ell$ for $\ell \not \in S$ is dense in $G_{\mathbb Q, S}$; this is Cebotarev's density theorem. In particular, any continuous representation $\rho: G_{\mathbb Q, S} \to \mathrm{GL}_n(L)$ (where $L/\mathbb Q_p$ is a finite extension) is determined by the $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_\ell)$ for $\ell \not \in S$.

A consequence is that $\rho|_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is also determined by $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_\ell)$, and in particular whether or not $\rho|_{G_{\mathbb Q_p}}$ satisfies some $p$-adic Hodge-theoretic property is also determined by the $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_\ell)$, in some seemingly inexplicit and complicated way.

Does anyone think it's possible that there is a "useful" and "explicit" (I'm not sure what these would mean in practice, which is why I'm putting quotes) condition depending only on the
matrices $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_\ell)$ which would imply that $\rho|_{G_{\mathbb Q_p}}$ is, say, Hodge-Tate? de Rham? semistable? crystalline? trianguline? any of these conditions with the word "potentially" in front of it?

I guess this could amount to understanding the topological structure of the Galois group in some level of gory detail, but I'm not sure.

Edit: for this to make sense, let's assume $\rho$ is semisimple.

Comment: Do you want to suppose $\rho$ irreducible (or semisimple)? Otherwise the question is hard to even formulate, since $\rho(\operatorname{Frob}_\ell)$ is only defined up to conjugacy +  the conjugacy classes won't give you enough data to distinguish between different extensions. Eg you can't distinguish between the direct sum $\mathbf{Q}_p \oplus \mathbf{Q}_p(3)$ and the non-de-Rham extension with the same composition factors, since they're both locally isomorphic at every $\ell \ne p$.

Comment: Oh whoops yes, I guess I do mean to say semisimple — I got confused about the issue of conjugacy classes.

Comment: OK, here's a random thought. If $\rho$ is irreducible + de Rham at p, then it should come from a pure motive, so there will be a number field $E$ such that the conj class of $\rho(Frob_\ell)$ is defined over $E$ for all $\ell$ and its eigenvalues are $\ell$-Weil numbers of some given weight. I wonder if it's realistic to expect a converse, i.e. that this algebraicity property of the Frobenii is sufficient to imply de Rham at p? Of course, even if true, it's utterly beyond reach of current methods to prove anything like that.

Comment: Even if that works, then I don't see how you could hope to get any finer properties of the local rep -- e.g. if $f$ is some modular form (normalised new cuspidal eigenform), and you know its level is not divisible by any prime except possibly 11 and 17, and you know $a_\ell(f)$ for every prime except those two, can you determine if its level is divisible by 11? I don't see how.